# Eliminar Cache desde una función de Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, cookies, cache, django-admin

```
1.-Tengo una aplicación que es accedida desde TABLETS. 
2.-La siguiente función consulta sobre un archivo en epecifico; por ejemplo en la ruta: archivos/01-05/2018/archivo1_version01.PDF 
3.-El archvio constantmente va tener cambios, sin embargo cuando ese archivo es modificado, en una computadora normal si se puede ver el nuevo archivo con los cambios realizados, pero cuando es consultado desde la TABLET sigue mostrando el archivo anterior. 

4.-Intente eliminar la cache, el historial en el navegador de la tablet, aveces funciona aveces NO, incluso es necesario reiniciar la tablet para que funcione.
```

¿Existe alguna forma de eliminar la CACHE desde mi funcion retView?

```
def retView(request):
    query=''
    msnNoExiste=''


    form= retailForm()
    if request.method=='GET':

        form1=retailForm(request.GET)

        if form1.is_valid():


            fgod = form1.cleaned_data.get('fg')



            query= Archivo.objects.filter(modelSerial=fgod, status=1)



    ctx={'form':form, 'query':query}
    return render(request,'app/retail.html',ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

tus importaciones quiza no sean las correctas, debes importar **cache**
de **django.core.cache** 
ejemplo:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.delete('mi_cache')
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentacion oficial
[Documentacion Oficial Cache Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#django-s-cache-framework)

Comment: el parametro que recibe cache.delete('') cómo lo defines?, cache.delete('mi_cache') se agrega al final de cada función?